# event.preventDefault() not working with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, preventdefault

I've been having some trouble with an AJAX form today. I've tried lots of things, yet can't get it to work.

My jQuery should prevent the form to submit. It has to go through AJAX. Yet, it seems to ignore event.preventDefault(); and just submits the form.

The form is part of 'single-page'. Single-page is a page which is loaded via AJAX. The form is a standard form with POST method.

Question:
Why does event.preventDefault() not work and how do I fix this issue?

Form:

```
<form id="comment-form" action="commentsystem.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Write a comment..." name="commentTxt" />
<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="postID" />
<div class="submit-btn">
    <img src="assets/images/checkmark.svg" />
    <input type="submit" value="" />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#comment-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $('#comment-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            $('.comment-container').append(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Commentsystem.php:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments (postID, userID, comment) VALUES ('$_POST[postID]', '$_SESSION[id]', '$_POST[commentTxt]')";

if ($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo '<p><span class="username">'.$_SESSION[id].'</span>'.$_POST[commentTxt].'</p>';
} else{
    echo 'Something went wrong while sending your comment.';
}
```

Comment: return `false` from the function

Comment: @DanielKrom - that's should not be necessary / useful, if `event.preventDefault` is being used: [.submit() docs](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Change - `$(form).attr('action')`- to `$('form').attr('action')`

Comment: Or to - `$(this).attr('action')`

Comment: Btw, you can check for javascript errors using firefox web developer feature so you know which exactly to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party! I recently had this issue, hoping this will help someone else. I'm not sure why this happened, but on my localhost the following worked fine but on production preventDefault wasn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', ".edit-form", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting normally
        var url = $(this).attr("action"); // where to post to
        // more code
        return false; // added for good measure(might not need)
    });
});
```

Apparently the .on() doesn't like being in $(document).ready(), and from some reading it doesn't need to be. Which is great if you are using it like I was, because I was replacing forms that also needed it.

So all you need to do is remove the $(document).ready(){}; and see if it works just like this.

```
$(document).on('submit', ".edit-form", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting normally
    var url = $(this).attr("action"); // where to post to
    // more code
    return false; // added for good measure(might not need)
});
```

As I said I'm not sure why this works, I haven't messed with jQuery in a long time, all I know is that it on my localhost preventDefault worked as expected and on production it ignored it. **If anyone could point me in the the right direction of why it would work on local and not production? It would be appreciated.** Maybe the hosting companies PHP settings? (haven't a clue, grasping at straws at this point)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself. Am posting my own answer because it might help out someone else.

I changed:

```
$('#comment-form').on('submit', function (event) {
```

to:

```
$(document).on("click",".comment-submit", function(event) {
```

Note that I added a class to my submit button in the form.
I have no idea why this is working, but it does. If anyone could explain, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: be careful, now, your users might be able to submit not with a click but with moving focus on submit button (with tab) then press enter

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll see what I can do to prevent that.

Comment: Can't you do `$(document).on("submit","#comment-form", function(event) {` to still handle "submit" and not "click"? The reason might is because your form HTML is itself created dynamically (by an earlier ajax call...you mentioned it in the question). Probably the form didn't exist at the point that your code ran to try and bind an event to it, and consequently the event did not get bound to anything because the jquery selector didn't match any elements. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ under the section "Direct and delegated events" for an explanation of the use case for this syntax.